# WebClient.UploadData "The underlying connection was closed"

Tags: vb.net, webclient, basecamp

I'm trying to upload a file from an FTP site to Basecamp using the Basecamp API.  I'm using a simple console application.  Here's my code:

```
Try
    Dim accountID As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("BaseCampID")
    Dim projectID As Integer = 9999999
    Dim folderName As String = "XXXXX/XXXXX"
    Dim fileName As String = "XXX.zip"

    'The URL to access the attachment method of the API
    Dim apiURL = String.Format("https://basecamp.com/{0}/api/v1/projects/{1}/attachments.json", accountID, projectID)

    'Get the file from the FTP server as a byte array
    Dim fileBytes As Byte() = GetFileBytes(String.Format("{0}\\{1}", folderName, fileName))

    'Initialize the WebClient object
    Dim client As New WebClient()
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/zip")
    'Need to provide a user-agent with a URL or email address
    client.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "Basecamp Upload (email@email.com)")
    'Keep the connection alive so it doesn't close
    client.Headers.Add("Keep-Alive", "true")

    'Provide the Basecamp credentials
    client.Credentials = New NetworkCredential("username", "password")

    'Upload the file as a byte array to the API, and get the response
    Dim responseStr As Byte() = client.UploadData(apiURL, "POST", fileBytes)

    'Convert the JSON response to a BaseCampAttachment object
    Dim attachment As BaseCampAttachment
    attachment = JSonHelper.FromJSon(Of BaseCampAttachment)(Encoding.Default.GetString(responseStr))

Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
Finally
    Console.ReadLine()
End Try
```

But whenever it calls client.UploadData, I get the error message "The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."  I ran into this issue earlier and thought I solved it by adding the "Keep-Alive" header, but it's not working anymore.  The API works if I upload a local file with client.UploadFile, but I'd like to just upload the file from they byte array from the FTP rather than downloading the file locally then uploading it to Basecamp.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: So you're saying the above code works when you run it on your machine, but not when you run it from the FTP server?  Are you getting any specific HTTP response codes or messages other than the connection closed?

Comment: It was running on my machine earlier in the day, but at some point it started receiving the connection closed message on my machine.  I didn't see any other HTTP response codes other than the connection closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never figured out what was wrong with the WebClient call, but I ended up using a Basecamp API wrapper from https://basecampwrapper.codeplex.com.  That wrapper uses HTTPRequest and HTTPResponse instead of WebClient.UploadData.  It's also much easier to just use that wrapper than to try writing my own code from scratch.